# How to scan ArrayList for string's length

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist, string-length

I have an ArrayList of strings sorted by length. I need to compare between strings that have the same length.

For example, an hypothetical list:

`["my", "by", "he", "she", "sun", "car"]`

I need to compare `"my"` only with `"by"` and `"he"`, `"she"` with only with `"sun"` and `"car"`.

In this code, for example, all strings are compared with eachother. Instead I want to compare for buckets due of computational problems. Thank you, guys.

```java
for(int i = 0; i<strings.size()-1; i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j<strings.size();j++) {
    System.out.println(strings.get(i).compareTo(strings.get(j)));     
  }
}
```

Comment: If your lists are small, what you're doing is just fine, simply add the length test, e.g. as suggested by Mureinik's answer. However, if your lists are large, you should rethink your data structures. You probably want a hash table of list, where your key is the size of the strings in the list and the value the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check for the string's length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size() - 1; i++) {
    String a = strings.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < strings.size(); j++) {
        String b = strings.get(j);
        if (a.length() == b.length()) {
            System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A huge advantage here is that the list is already sorted by increasing length. And if it wasn't, then just sort it by length first then apply the operation that you desire here. Or if you don't want to sort by length, in the example below, change the `break` to `continue`.

Given that you have a sorted list, the main thing then is just to add a check that the first string to be compared matches in length to the second string to be compared. And if they don't match in length, then you can just go to the next word in the outer loop, since you will have been guaranteed to see all the words with the same length already, since the list is sorted:

```
for(int i = 0; i<strings.size()-1; i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j<strings.size(); j++) {
    if (strings.get(i).length() != strings.get(j).length()) break;
    System.out.println(strings.get(i).compareTo(strings.get(j)));   
  }
}
```

Note this will work whether the list is sorted increasing length or decreasing length.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution and it's working very well. Bye

Comment: @LorenzoAlighieri You're welcome, glad to help. If you agree, could you mark this answers as accepted? It benefits both of our reputations as "new contributors" to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also create buckets based on a certain property using `Collectors#partitioningBy` of the Java Stream API.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = yourList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(String::length));
```

Then you can process each bucket by providing the size:

```
int length = 3;
List<String> bucket = map.get(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first split the list into groups/partitions of strings with same length. Once you have the groups/partitions created, you can simply run the code that you have given above. In that case, the worst time complexity still remains O(n^2) but in other scenarios it is improved. In best case scenario it will be O(n). Below code will give an idea of what I am saying. I am using groupingBy method from Java Streams API.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("me");
list.add("by");
list.add("he");
list.add("she");
list.add("sun");
list.add("car");

Map<Integer, List<String>> mapOfSameLengthStrings = list
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));

for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> entry : mapOfSameLengthStrings.entrySet()) {
    List<String> listOfSameLengthStrings = entry.getValue();
    for(int i = 0; i<listOfSameLengthStrings.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j<listOfSameLengthStrings.size();j++) {
                System.out.println(listOfSameLengthStrings.get(i).compareTo(listOfSameLengthStrings.get(j)));
        }
    }
}
```

Output of above code is below:

```
11
5
-6
-13
16
16
```

It makes 6 comparisons, which is what you need as per my understanding of your query. Hope it helped.